# L2TP IPsec VPN client configuration

Tags: linux, configuration, vpn

I have Linux (Fedora) box and I want to conject to VPN described as "L2TP IPsec VPN" one. I have got following credentials:

---

user=xxxxxxxxx

pass=xxxxxxxxx

VPN server= XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

IPsec key=xxxxxxxxx

---

I tried to use NetworkManager, vpnc with no luck. What software to use?

Comment: News on this? I've the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to go with following packages:

> 1. pptp 2.4.3
> 2. openswan 2.4.14
> 3. l2tpd 0.69 [ patched with l2tpd-0.69.sysv.patch ]
> 4. Kernel configuration, of course.

These packages are enough to make your Operating System L2TP_IPSec capable.

Comment: could you please be more especific? I'm searching for this same issue and could not found a solution yet!